# WCF to WCF. The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, wcf

We have two WCF services and first with api web method. In interface created like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
   Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
)]
RequestParams GetAccount(RequestParams requestParams);
```

I want to call this method from second WCF service. Like this:

```
try
{
   var myBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
   var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);

   using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IAccount>(myBinding, myEndpoint))
   {
       IAccount apiService = null;

       try
       {
           factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
           apiService = factory.CreateChannel();

           result = apiService.GetAccount(requestParams);

           ((ICommunicationObject)apiService).Close();
           factory.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Fatal(ex);
           (apiService as ICommunicationObject)?.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

When I check GetAccount method with use Postman, it works and return expected value. But when I try to call from second service method is not called (checked in debug mode) and in catch in exception - (400) Bad Request.
I think this error is related with json format for returned value. When I try to change to xml in interface, method is called (checked with debug mode). How I can configure WebHttpBehaviour for use json? Thanks

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Yes. it was helpful. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually caused by WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse. If you change WebMessageBodyStyle to Wrapped, WCF will encapsulate the object again. Here is a demo:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat =
        WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse
 )]
        string GetAccount(UserData requestParams);
```

WrappedResponse will encapsulate the response.

[image]

Because your WebMessageBodyStyle is WrappedRequest, the object you send on the client side must be encapsulated, otherwise 400 Bad Request will appear.

I think the best solution is to set WebMessageBodyStyle to Bare, Here is a demo:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat =
        WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
 )]
        string GetAccount(UserData requestParams);
    }
    [DataContract(Name = "user")]
    public class UserData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetAccount(UserData requestParams)
        {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service Open");
            Console.ReadKey();
            selfHost.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is Program.cs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>

            <service name="ConsoleApp113.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8012/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>

                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="ConsoleApp113.IService1"
                          behaviorConfiguration="ESEndPointBehavior" />
            </service>
        </services>


        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>

        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is web.config.

```
class Program
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat =
            WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
     )]
            string GetAccount(UserData requestParams);
        }
        [DataContract(Name = "user")]
        public class UserData
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
            var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8012/ServiceModelSamples/service");

            using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint))
            {
                    IService1 apiService = null;
                    factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                    apiService = factory.CreateChannel();
                    UserData userData = new UserData();
                    userData.Email = "Test";
                    userData.Name = "Test";
                    userData.Password = "Test";
                    string result = apiService.GetAccount(userData);
                    ((ICommunicationObject)apiService).Close();
                    factory.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
              
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the client code.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, there is no such setting in WCF. But you can encapsulate a wrapped type object yourself:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class GetAccount {
        [DataMember(Name = "RequestParams ")]
        public RequestParams requestParams ;
    }
```

You can encapsulate RequestParams into GetAccount, and then send GetAccount directly to the server. So in order to successfully call the WCF service you have to modify the service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
   Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
)]
RequestParams GetAccount(GetAccount requestParams);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't change BodyStyle, this endpoint is being used by another frontend application, Maybe I can setup webHttpBinding for use json and wrappedRequest?